# Has anyone successfully connected to Google Contacts using ServiceConnect in V11?

Tags: web-access, webservices

When I call:  `googlecontacts = ServiceConnect["GoogleContacts"]`

The "Wolfram Connector" widget pops up and I click on "Sign in to Google Contacts" which directs me to an Error 400 page at Google with the error message:  Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, https://www.wolfram.com/oauthlanding/?service=GoogleContacts, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

It seems like I may need to adjust some OAuth settings in Google but I'm not up to speed on Google OAuth settings. Curious if anyone has recently run into this and knows the path to success.

My goal is simply to pull some Google Contact data into my notebook.

Thanks!

Comment: This now works correctly after updating to 11.1.0.0